# iOS 7 - TabelView editável

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Estou tentando criar uma TableView com as ações (Add/Edit/Delete rows) iguais do app nativo (Telefone) conforme imagem abaixo, mas não estou conseguindo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de criar um campo "(+) adicionar item" (que insere uma nova linha) e em seguida um formulário com campos onde, eu clico e já posso editá-lo, inserir informações como etiquetas (ex: Casa, Móvel, Comercial), número de telefone, e-mail, além do botão delete(-)

Answer (score 4):

Para isso você precisa criar uma UITableViewCell personalizada. 
Vamos focar o problema na inserção de dados exatamente como o de adicionar telefone.
Primeiro, faça um UITableViewCell como essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para isso, não precisa de uma subclass de UITableViewCell pois a nativa já possui tudo o que vc precisa. Monte o layout (storyboard) apenas insira um botão na celula, e uma label, e instancie a cell segundo o seu identifier. A ação dessa cell no didSelectRowAtIndexPath será um insertRowsAtIndexPaths, que irá inserir uma cell customizada:

Crie Uma nova classe que estende de UITableViewCell, e monte o layout (storyboard) dela como o abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa UITableViewCell é mais complexa, ela possui várias funcionalidades, como o botão que seleciona o tipo de telefone, o swipe, etc... isso tudo deverá ser implementado nessa UITableViewCell customizada.

Acredito que os links abaixo poderão te ajudar a seguir esse caminho:

**Para entender o delegate da seleção da Cell:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404922/uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

**Para entender como criar uma UITableViewCell customizada**
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

**Para criar uma Cell com swipe**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView swipeAccessoryButtonPushedForRowAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254402/swipe-to-delete-and-the-more-button-like-in-mail-app-on-ios-7

A sua pergunta não possui uma dúvida direta, ela engloba uma série de técnicas. De qualquer forma espero que isso ajude.